# Zurb Foundation - slide out menus

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Doing some reading I there are mentions that Zurb Foundation has something that supports side slide-out menus, similar to the one that can be found on the following website (triggers via the icon on the top left corner): http://www.dtelepathy.com/

Looking at foundations doco I'm unable to find anything.  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on how to achieve such behavior with Zurb Foundation?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something for Foundation 3 called off canvas slides. I am not sure that this is compatitible with Foundation 4.

http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

Answer (score 0):

The one you're looking at on http://www.dtelepathy.com is drawjs:
http://codepen.io/rolandjitsu/pen/CgmGd